# Android font-size brakes UI

Tags: android, css, web

On my web project I encountered a problem with android phones. If you just browse a page with default settings all is fine, but if in Settings > Display > Font > I change font-size to e.g. Huge then my UI elements become scaled.

I style my elements using em's mostly.

I tried fixes on topic of **font boosting**:

```
html * {max-height:9999999px}
```

or

```
text-size-adjust: none
```

In short, imagine I have 4 buttons stacked at the bottom of the screen horizontally. When I change the font size in android settings the buttons become huge and overlap each other, hence breaking the UI

Please help. :)

**UPDATE**
The accepted answer suggests that is is not possible from a css/js perspective. There may be some crazy hacks, but nothing worth thinking about for me. So if anyone finds a solution, please do post an answer.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your question is. What is it that is a problem for you, and what is it you want to achieve? Could you possibly include images of what it looks like when it breaks and what you want it to look like?

Comment: I'm sorry if I am not completely clear. In short, e.g. I have 4 buttons stacked at the bottom of the screen horizontally. When changing the font size in android settings the buttons become huge and overlap each other, hence breaking the UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior from Android Accessibility options.

As far as my knowledge goes there is no way to hack that from external css/js in the browser.

If you have a standalone app you can extend the `WebView` class and do `getSettings().setTextZoom(100)` which would ignore the text size from Accessibility.

Comment: No, no standalone app. Just a web app.

Comment: Unfortunately there is nothing you can do - thats the way it's supposed to be displayed

Comment: To clarify, what's happening is that the device changes the relative perception of pixels, so that 1px becomes e.g. the same as 5px (in normal conditions)?

Comment: By default Android uses density independent pixels (`dp`, or `sp` in the case of text) Those get scaled based on the screen density by a factor from 0,5 to 4. The accessibility setting applies further scaling, so there is no direct link with pixel size

Comment: So what happens is just everything... zooms in ? Sorry, I just don't understand the dp, sp thing

Comment: If you are interested you can take a look at this documentation  [link] (https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 1):

In CSS **em** unit is relative to the font-size of the element (2em means 2 times the size of the current font). 
Which means that it's dependent of the user's font settings.

The solution to your problem is to use another unit, like **vw**, which is relative the screen (viewport) width,  *9vw ~ 9% of viewport width*.

Or simply use an independent unit like pixels (**px**).

More about CSS units can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp.

Comment: Hmm, I do not believe this would work because as far as I have seen, it seems that changing font-size on android changes the size of a pixel i.e. 1px becomes 5px. Because I have sizes set in px as well

Comment: Also, changing all sizes to vw is probably not a good idea and would take too much time

Comment: px units are also changed by the Android font setting.